# minifab floating action button in fragment not clickable

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-animation, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button inside a fragment with 3 other minifabs that animate out of it in an arc.  The main FAB is working just fine and calls the animation on the miniFabs, but the miniFabs are not clickable for some reason.  I can easily access all the Fab's, but cannot access the `setOnClickListener()` of the minifabs.  Here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/chatter"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chatter_video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_first_menu_item_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/right_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chatter_new_video"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chatter_open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_main_right_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chatter_new" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chatter_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_first_menu_item_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/right_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chatter_new_photo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_chatter_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_first_menu_item_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/right_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chatter_new_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_chatter_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.45"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@color/mainColor"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am animating fab_chatter_open with this code which works just fine.  Clicking animation and all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

and reversing this animation on clicking the FAB a second time.

Then I am animating the miniFabs with this code.  The animation on the miniFabs works just fine, but the FABs are not clickable in any way:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate android:fromXDelta="82%p" android:toXDelta="65%p"
        android:fromYDelta="7%p" android:toYDelta="7%p"
        android:duration = "100"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="100"/>
</set>
```

You'll also notice a `Linearlayout` at the bottom.  This is to cover the recyclerView with an alpha of 50% to keep the focus on the fabs and dim the content.  Unfortunately, it doesn't cover the actionbar or the bottom navigation like I'd prefer.  If you have suggestions for accomplishing that as well, please let me know.

Comment: I do believe it has something to do with the `translate` animation.  If I set the miniFabs to visible the whole time, I can click on the miniFab before the animation is done.  Once teh animation starts, the miniFab is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in a constrained layout when you animate a floating action button with `translate`, the click of the button stays where the FAB was originally drawn when the view was created and inflated.  I decided instead to use the margin bottom and margin end on my miniFabs floating action buttons:

```
android:layout_marginBottom=""
android:layout_marginEnd=""
```

to place the floating action buttons on the screen where I wanted when the view is originally drawn and inflated in relation to the main FAB.  Also, since this is a constrained layout, I used:

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

to put the buttons in the bottom right corner where the main FAB is located otherwise the margin-bottom and margin-top of these miniFabs would be much harder to calculate.

Then I am using the animate `alpha` and animate `scale` on the miniFabs.  This keeps the miniFabs in the same place for the click events but gives them some animation so they have a little flair.

I also made sure to set the `isEnabled()` property of each FAB to false once I set their visibility to gone otherwise the click event will still be there.